# Object detection on fairly constant background

Tags: object-detection

**Problem**
I am trying to solve an object detection problem where the background remains relatively consistent and I am only interested in the positions of the objects.

A perfect fit of the bounding box for the object is not necessary!

Below are schematic images to help understand the problem (reality will look different).
[image]

[image]

*Background*
You can see that the background is almost the same.
However, the background can change due to different sunlight, dirt, small camera displacements or small displacements of the background object itself.

*Objects of Interest*
The size, colour and shape of objects can vary greatly and change over time.

*Given Data*
I can produce an arbitrary amount of background images.
I can produce an arbitrary amount of unlabeled data, for which it is not clear if an object is present or not.

**What I've Tried**
I tried to fine tune [PyTorchs Faster Rcnn](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/faster_rcnn.html), but the results are very poor. Apparently, transfer learning is a bit tricky for object detection, [see](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.13502.pdf).

**Some Ideas**

- Of course you could use YOLO. However, the current licence costs about 100K and I think this particular problem could be solved much cheaper.
- Since the background is fairly constant and I don't need really high precision and I can produce a lot of semi-labelled data, I am considering doing the following:

1. Take small sections of the images of size CxC and train a CNN: CxC -> D, where D is a vector, using contrastive learning on the unlabeled data.
2. Add a fully connected layer to the CNN, s.t. CNN': CxC -> D -> R^2, where the output gives the class probabilities (i.e. foreground or background).
3. Then train respectively fine-tune the CNN' with some labelled data (recall that we have an arbitrary number of background images).
4. Inference: Divide an image into regions of size CxC and apply CNN' to all regions.
   Combine neighboring cells with some algorithm to find connected regions (e.g. if two neighboring cells are of type foreground, consider them as one object; if a cell A is labelled background but all its neighbors are foreground, consider A as foreground, ...).

Feel free to roast this procedure and/or point me to a paper that does something similar.